# Map [0, infinity] to [0, 1]

Tags: sequences-and-series

I'm creating a julia set visualisation.

I want the colour per point to be based off the iteration final value, $f(z_n)$, instead of the traditional: number of iterations before reaching a cut-off (usually when any component, real or imaginary, of $z$ is $>2$).

How could I from from something like:

$0, 0.5^n, 1^n, 1.5^n  ...$ to:

$0, 0.1, 0.2, 0.25, ...$

I don't expect the number 1 to ever be reached, in the output set.

I also expect there to be an arbitrary parameter, defining how rapidly the curve of the mapping works

Comment: $1/x - 1$ maybe

Comment: Are you sure you want the first $3$ results in arithmetic progression?

Comment: @J.G. I assigned values from my head, they're not way realistic

Comment: @RobinNicole $1/0.5 > 1$

Comment: We can map from $[0,\,1]$ to $[0,\,\infty]$ with $1/x-1$, or back with $1/(1+x)$. An order-preserving variant would be $x/(1+x)$, the inverse of $x/(1-x)$.

Comment: @J.G.  perfect, I was reluctant to use the inverse tan answer due to performance costs. This should work well.

Comment: @RobinNicole I misread your comment, that was indeed what I wanted

Answer (score 7):

A quick way to do this is to take some function such as $\tan^{-1}(x)$, which maps the interval $[0, \infty)$ to $[0, \pi/2)$. We can then rescale this by $\frac{1}{\pi/2}$, to arrive at:

$$\frac{\tan^{-1}(x)}{\pi / 2}: [0, \infty) \rightarrow [0, 1)$$

Comment: Or arctan(kx)/(pi/2) for any k

Answer (score 4):

I think
$$f(x)=\frac{x}{x+e^{-tx}}$$
$$g(x)=1-\frac1{tx+1}$$
where $t\gt0$ will do what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Just to write up my comment, $y=\frac{x}{1+x}$ is an order-preserving map from $[0,\,\infty]$ to $[0,\,1]$. It is of interest, albeit not for computation, that it admits the parameterisation $x=\tan^2 t,\,y=\sin^2 t$, or alternatively $x=\sinh^2 u,\,y=\tanh^2 u$. We can even [relate these parameterisations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gudermannian_function#Some_identities) viz. $t=\operatorname{gd}u$.

Comment: https://imgur.com/NGvw0Tx, heres the fractal I got using my technique. Does this seem like garbage?

Comment: @Tobi Try replacing $y$ with $y^p$, then vary $p$ to see whether you get something you like better.

Comment: Okay, it was a bug. I now get satisfactory smooth Julia set visualisations, compared to the traditional type you get when you cut off: https://imgur.com/r3Qi144

Comment: Do you know how I'd scale $[0:max] -> [0: 1]$? instead.

Comment: @Tobi How about $\frac{2x}{x+\max}$?